# Log4j Class Name, File Name and Line Number Not Displayed in Log Entries

Tags: java, log4j

When looking through my log4j log file I noticed that sometimes the Class Name, File Name and Line Number are not retrieved and only a ? is displayed.

```
2016-07-15 14:04:01,665 DEBUG [WebContainer : 0] ? (?:?) - ID:12345678 - Request Received for Inbound Disposition Process.
```

It is obvious that the PatternLayout specifies that they should be there, and other parameters such as the date and priority are displaying properly.

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
</layout>
```

I know that the configuration file and priority can also be set on the server, but is there an option to disable certain parameters in the PatternLayout such that they only display a question mark?

I'm not sure if it matters but I'm running on WAS7.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713429/in-log4j-why-c-in-conversionpattern-prints-question-mark-with-asyncappen

Comment: Ahhh, excellent. I am indeed using AsyncAppender.